# "instantiating a derived class object" - C++

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

I am new to C++ and learning the basics of this language. I read this line in a book "Instantiating a derived-class object begins a chain of constructor calls". Can someone please explain what does this statement means? There was no explaination given in the book. Please help.

Comment: Like [this](http://ideone.com/EN9sDQ).

Comment: can you plz explain it in simple words. I am not good in programming :(

Comment: @AjmalKhan: You may wish to spend some more time studying so that you will understand the answers. You can always come back to this later.

Comment: If A is a child of B and B is a child of C, in order to instantiate a C, you will need to construct an A, then a B, then finally a C.

Comment: why do you tag c++11?

Comment: @Stefano: Presumably the OP is learning C++11.

Answer (score 4):

It means that if you have a base class and a derived class:

```
struct A
{
   A() { std::cout << "constructing A\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
   B() { std::cout << "constructing B\n"; }
};
```

then instantiating the derived class:

```
int main()
{
   B b;
}
```

invokes the constructor not only for the derived class, but also for the base class:

```
constructing A
constructing B
```

and this "chain" of automatically-invoked constructors gets longer the more bases you have (i.e. the deeper your inheritance tree goes).

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining an object hierarchy, and observe the effects from the execution of the constructors yourself. Here's a contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int nValue) {
        std::cout << "A: " << nValue << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B: public A
{
    B(int nValue, double dValue)
    : A(nValue) {
        std::cout << "B: " << dValue << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C: public B
{
    C(int nValue, double dValue, char chValue)
    : B(nValue, dValue) {
        std::cout << "C: " << chValue << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C cClass(5, 4.3, 'R');
    return 0;
}
```

Can you imagine more complex hierarchies? What happens with other kinds of constructors? What about destructors?

Answer (score 0):

A derived class is a class which inherits from another class. I suppose you're familiar with inheritance,somewhat. The derived class inherits the constructor of the base class, you just have to "override" it. So when you instantiate an object from the derived class, first the constructor of the base class is called and then the constructor of the derived class.

Comment: You cannot override a constructor.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the override term in programming languages,but more  the term from the English language. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

To [*instantiate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instantiate) something you create an *instance* of it:

> instantiate
>
> ...
>
> (transitive) To represent (something) by a concrete instance.

In class-based languages like C++ you have *classes*, which acts as blueprints, and then you have *objects* which are instances of specific classes.

For example, lets say you have a class `A`. If you then declare an object `a` of the class `A` then you *instantiate* an object of the class `A`.